# ARM template for - Subscription Reader and Azure Resources Contributor Role (Then Assign with Blueprint)

Tags: azure, templates, roles, azure-resource-manager, blueprint

I am trying to write a custom policy where-in I can use that for the below use case as described.
Use case for reference -
Custom Role for a User who should be the Subscription Reader and the Contributor for the Azure Resource level.
This will need in the form of ARM template and then I finally will deploy using the Blueprint and assign the same template.
Can someone Please help on how if you have any sample code?

Comment: Step one is that you check the documentation and try yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Comment: Sure Sir @Daniel.. I will look on that But if I need help let me get back to you to get if you any direct code...

Comment: It is good if you read this one before asking questions too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In Azure Blueprints, you can directly add the Role Assignment Artifact and the assign that role through Blueprint.

Comment: @Jagrati Modi - Role assignment is at the Subscription and service level, i think we cant take it from there, we need to have a custom role

Comment: You can assign Built-in Roles to Azure Resource groups & Azure Resources